# C++ Tool Equivalent to Java XDoclet

Tags: c++, annotations, xdoclet

I'm looking for a way to add annotations to my C++ source.  Is there any XDoclet/Javadoc style tools available for C++?

Answer (score 2):

See [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). But it only generates documentation. If you want to generate some boilerplate code on basis of your tags, you needs something else. Personally, I didn't hear about such well-known tool for C++.